# Trouble returning with a Pyramid backend and a React JS frontend

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, rest, pyramid

I am developping a RESTful API with a Pyramid backend and a JS frontend.
The frontend can send JSON to the backend and the backend can receive.

I tested the frontend with [JSONplaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and It worked, It could send and receive.
It seems like the backend can send but the frontend receive this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Here is the backend code :

```python
@view_config(route_name="route", renderer="json", request_method='POST')
def chatbot(req_received):
    #We get the message from the frontend : client's message
    message = req_received.json_body["message"]
    return {"response":"received"}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route('route', '/')
        config.scan()
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    #Host / Port / Application
    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 3000, app)    
    print("RUNNING ...")
    server.serve_forever()
```

And Here is the error received from the frontend while the backend is sending :

> Error: Network Error
> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It is not necessary to add EDITED to your post. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67410602/revisions) tracks all changes that are made once you've posted here.

Comment: What is the complete request that you send to Pyramid? Please include headers and JSON body. Next, when you  send an HTTP post request to port 3000, what is the response? Your Pyramid code looks OK to me, except for the argument `req_received` instead of `request`, as in the Renderers example at the bottom of https://trypyramid.com/.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)
I finally found that it was a Cross-origin resource sharing case. 
I add a header and that works well